# Sharepoint List, change ownership

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, list

I am trying to change ownership to a sharepoint list as I am leaving my company. The approval person who gets requests for access must be changed to someone else.

Can this be done? I could not find anything online on changing this.

Comment: Are you looking for SharePoint access requests settings? If yes, check this documentation: [Set up and manage access requests](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-up-and-manage-access-requests-94b26e0b-2822-49d4-929a-8455698654b3). Let me know if this works.

Comment: List Access, which i believe is different then SP access

Comment: There are no access requests settings for particular lists, it's at site level. If you want to change/grant the permissions for list, you can do it from list settings (if inheritance is broken, else you can grant access at site level which will be automatically inherited by your list).

Answer (score 1):

There is no single access request setting for the list items, it's included in the site, so you can just add the user as the site owner and it's enough.

[image]

**Updated answer**:

[image]

Comment: Cant seem to find this option.

Comment: Please check the updated answer.